# ggplot2 horizontal strip text on left side of figure?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, facet-wrap

I want to place the strip labels for faceted rows of a ggplot2 figure on the left-hand size in horizontal orientation.

I am able to place strip label text in horizontal orientation if I keep strips on the right (e.g., `g_strip_text_horiz`, or can move the strips to the left outside y-axes (e.g., `g_strip_text_left`), but cannot do both.

Look forward to your recommendations, and thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble(rownames = "model") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-model, names_to = "measure", values_to = "value")

g_strip_text_horiz <- df %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram() +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(rows = ggplot2::vars(measure),
                      scales = "free_y") +
  ggplot2::theme_classic() +
  ggplot2::theme(
    strip.background.y = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text.y = ggplot2::element_text(angle = 0))

print(g_strip_text_horiz)
```

[image: rendered image, g_strip_text_horiz]

```
g_strip_text_left <- df %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram() +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(rows = ggplot2::vars(measure),
                      scales = "free_y",
                      switch = "y") +
  ggplot2::theme_classic() +
  ggplot2::theme(
    strip.background.y = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text.y = ggplot2::element_text(angle = 90))

print(g_strip_text_left)
```

[image: rendered image, g_strip_text_left]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be a bit more explicit by using `strip.text.y.left`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = value)) +
  ggplot2::geom_histogram() +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(
    rows = ggplot2::vars(measure),
    scales = "free_y",
    switch = "y"
  ) +
  ggplot2::theme_classic() +
  ggplot2::theme(
    strip.background.y = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text.y.left = ggplot2::element_text(angle = 0)
  )
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @stefan !  Nice to discover a new set of params that you wouldn't have known to look for previously. Appreciate the help!